# Not getting response after submitting form with ajax to php also part of script is not executed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have problem submitting form with ajax, or to be more accurate it submits the form and data is saved in db in another file but nothing works after that. Another gile (php) returns short html but it does not come out here? Also loading form is not faded in and after that nothing is faded in or out.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    var thisForm = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fadeOut(function(){
      $("#loading").fadeIn(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: thisForm.attr("action"),
          data: thisForm.serialize(),
          success: function(data){
            $("#loading").fadeOut(function(){
              $("#success").text(data).fadeIn();
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  })
});
</script>
```

Here is form starting:

```
<form action="regit.php" method="post">
```

I don't put complete form here cause script submits form as should to php file that inserts it in db. Also php file gives html response back but then my script hangs. It works perfectly that (excluding fadein of loading div) far it submits data but everything after that is left undone. So there must be flow.. I got it working in another instance where it returns html but also prints html directly to screen, i wonder if there is way to display html as html so it looks ok and links etc. works? Another instance has identical code, different file and different form but identical script and it works...

This form that submits data is inside div.

So where have i gone to forest with this...?

Comment: I would suggest you pick up a debugger. Use Firebug for FF, or the built-in console in Chrome. There you can see the request being made, ande tramp their data. However, I believe Chrome doesn't log async requests, which I know for sure Firebug does.

Comment: Yes i use Firebug and that was the weirdest cause it said data is coming back but i found the problem which was duplicated div names...

How can i get the data that is coming back to variable without printing it to screen? So i can process it to better for in javascript?